# What are the differences between the two Estimator in the qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Recently, I have been completing a VQE code and implementing the VQE algorithm for noisy models. However, during this process, I discovered that there are two types of Estimators provided in different tutorials.

```
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
```

I tested them separately and encountered the following confusion:
A shortened version of my code is as follows:

```
def UCCSD_VQE(hamiltonian, n_particles, num_qubits....):
    seed = 170
    algorithm_globals.random_seed = seed    
    num_particles = [n_particles // 2, n_particles // 2]
    mapper = JordanWignerMapper()
    converter = QubitConverter(mapper=mapper)
    hf = HartreeFock(qubit_converter=converter, num_particles=num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals=num_qubits // 2)
    ansatz = UCCSD(qubit_converter=converter, num_particles=num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals=num_qubits // 2, initial_state=hf, generalized=False, preserve_spin=True)
    optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=1000)
    estimator = Estimator()
    vqe = VQE(estimator, ansatz=ansatz, optimizer=optimizer)
    vqe.initial_point = np.zeros(ansatz.num_parameters)
    result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(hamiltonian)
    circ = result.optimal_circuit.bind_parameters(result.optimal_parameters)
   
    print(result)
    print(f"VQE on Aer qasm simulator (no noise): {result.optimal_value.real:.8f}")
    print(f"Delta from reference energy value is {(result.optimal_value.real - ref_value):.8f}")
```

If this is the setting, the result is relatively good. I calculated LiH with a molecular spacing of 2.8, and the returned result is as follows:

```
 'optimizer_time': 25.174492597579956}
VQE on Aer qasm simulator (no noise): -7.80622948
Delta from reference energy value is 0.00000008
```

You can find time is approximately 25 seconds, and the error from the reference value is also within 0.00000008.

When I switch the simulator "from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator", my setting is：

```
try:
   noiseless_estimator = AerEstimator(
                            run_options={"seed": seed},
                            transpile_options={"seed_transpiler": seed},)
   noiseless_estimator.set_options(device='GPU')
except AerError as e:
   print("Failed to initialize GPU estimator in creating no_Real_Noisy_model:", str(e))
   noiseless_estimator = AerEstimator(
                            run_options={"seed": seed},
                            transpile_options={"seed_transpiler": seed},)

vqe = VQE(noiseless_estimator, ansatz=ansatz, optimizer=optimizer)
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged.

I have two pieces of NVIDIA GTX3090Ti, but the results after modifying this code are very poor.

```
'optimizer_time': 899.3149755001068}
VQE on Aer qasm simulator (no noise): -7.81485699
Delta from reference energy value is -0.00862743
```

You can see that not only has the running time of the program increased, but also the accuracy has decreased.

My question is:

1. Why does this phenomenon occur?
2. How can I set it up to fix this problem?

My Virtual Environment Settings：

```
qiskit                   0.39.2
qiskit-aer               0.11.1
qiskit-aer-gpu           0.11.2
qiskit-ibmq-provider     0.19.2
qiskit-nature            0.5.0
qiskit-terra             0.22.2
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to read this article [What are Qiskit Primitives?](https://medium.com/qiskit/what-are-qiskit-primitives-9bf63c1eacc7) which describes the primitives. Qiskit IBM Runtime also has an Estimator.

How each Estimator behaves can be configured. By default the qiskit.primitives Estimator produces an ideal result (no sampling/shot noise). The [Aer Estimator](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.primitives.Estimator.html) however defaults to using a sampling mode so will incur shot noise and the way the expectation value is computed is different too - a circuit will be run for each pauli or group thereof in the operator (see the `abelian_grouping` parameter in the above API ref link). To have a similar behavior outcome to the default configured `qiskit.primitives` Estimator you would set Aer Estimator `approximation` parameter to `True` and `shots` to `None`. If so, it calculates the exact expectation values. Otherwise, it calculates expectation values with sampling.